# I want to make a Update with select then addition with Define

Tags: mysql, sql

Example:
I have a table name Quest and have a column named FLAGS

```
FLAGS = 1 =>TEXT = CHARM
FLAGS = 2 =>TEXT = DISORIENTED
FLAGS = 4 =>TEXT = DISARM
FLags = 536870912 =>TEXT = Saped
```

etc...

I want to make a SQL query like this .

```
    Update quest set RESULTinText = 'TOTALFLAGSINTEXT' WHERE FLAGS = TOTALFLAGS in flag column;
```

If flags =1 then the result will be - CHARM in the RESULTinText Column.

But if it is FLAGS 1 + Flags 2 (3) Result will Be CHARM and Disoriented in the RESULTinText Column.

Comment: Whilst the sanity or not of storing a bit-field in an SQL database can be debated, then *also* storing the text representation seems a mistake. Why should this be stored in the database at all? If someone does decide to take a stab at answering this, they'll almost certainly need to know what database system you're using also.

Comment: I need this because i want to show the total flags by text in my website cause number doesnt really inform the users. Im using mysql database.

Comment: But why not build up the description in whatever intermediate language you're using that's querying the database and building the rest of the web page? Or (please don't take this seriously) why are you not generating full-blown HTML instead of just a string of text?

Comment: Cause im not good at PHP and HTML and i can do it with SQL database i just need a little help for making this work i know im a noob :) I have no problem to show FLAGS number in the website but i dont want so show the number i want to show what it does.

Comment: It would be a better place to do it. Put it this way - you don't know how to do it in *either* PHP or SQL at the moment. I'd seriously recommend you learn to do it in PHP.

Comment: In my opinion not really cause anyway i will need to ask the server to make a querry into my database .

Comment: Comma-separated values in a column or anything which is in this direction is a really, really bad idea in databases. It's the violation of the first normal form.

Comment: Ok thanks all i will try to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a handful of values, it sounds like the MySQL `set` type is what you are looking for.  It does exactly what you want, storing values efficiently in a bit representation and then allowing you to retrieve them as strings.

This is best described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html).

There are limitations on sets, such as only supporting up to 64 elements.  Personally I generally avoid them, because the right "set-based" approach is to have a separate table with each of the values and a match-table.  However, for a quick-and-dirty application it might be just the right thing.

Comment: The list of all my FLAGS and TEXT . https://www.privatepaste.com/7b2c4229de  but if i need to create a column for each text this will be too much i think. Can see an other example here http://archive.trinitycore.info/Creature_template_tc2#mechanic_immune_mask